# Canvas и svg, возможность совмещения координат

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, path

Хочу использовать paths из svg для перемещения элементов, нарисованных на canvas.

Нужный мне рисунок был в `png`(электросхема), пережал в `svg`, получил нужные `paths`, всё работает, но в процессе конвертации `paths` стали огромными (а в `svg` прописались `scale` и `transform`, картинка выводится как надо) и мои элементы `canvas` летают по реальным, длинным `paths`.

Пробовал scale для canvas, не получилось. Как трансформировать paths или canvas чтобы выводимый рисунок совпадал по размерам с анимацией?

Comment: Дайте минимальный пример кода что вы реализовали

Comment: @Razmik Galstyan  могу через 40 минут, такое ограничение на сайте..

Comment: @Razmik Galstyan Хотя урезанный вариант есть в моих предыдущих вопросах (их всего три, только учусь..), без svg файла.